# Make Script / Object load last

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a webpage which lags while loading, because an embedded object is trying to be processed... My webpage load sequentially, but the script delays the entire page because it appears at the top...

Is it possible to have the script / object load last, but still have it appear at the top of the page?

Comment: What kind of object is it? Can you show (the relevant part of) your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the `defer="defer"` or `async="true"` attributes?

EDIT: If we're talking about a `<script>` tag in the first place.

Comment: What does this do? In which browsers? It didn't seem to have affect when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

As a last recourse, you can remove the element from the page HTML, and write it back using JavaScript once the page has finished loading.